# Profiling memory usage (heap, stack, OpenCL buffers for GPUs) on the Android devices

Tags: android, arm, gpu, opencl, mali

I am trying to precisely measure the total amount of memory used by my application. I am developing a .so library that utilizes GPUs on the phone devices. I am mostly using C/C++ and OpenCL in my development, hence, all my memory allocations are either `new/delete` or `clCreateBuffer/clReleaseMemObject`.

Precisely, I am looking for the following values:

1. Total memory used on the heap
2. Total memory used on the stack (if possible)
3. Total memory used for the OpenCL buffers

**What I did:**

I used `dumpsys` to collect some numbers using the following command:

`adb shell dumpsys meminfo com.example.hellolibs.debug  -d`

And, I also wrote some simple profiling code to track all the OpenCL buffer allocations/frees (I am tracking the reference counters of the underlying OpenCL buffers). The total memory usage that I am measuring using my profiling code is bigger than what `dumpsys` is reporting using the above command. It shouldn't be like that, right?

My target platform is: ARM CPUs with Mali GPUs

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want Streamline, a performance profiler that is part of Arm Mobile Studio:
https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/graphics-and-gaming/arm-mobile-studio/components/streamline-performance-analyzer

Mobile Studio is free, and there are some good video tutorials for it.

Comment: Does the Streamline profiler also work with simple binaries on the target (not packed inside an apk but cross-compiled with the android ndk)? If so, if there documentation about that? How would I capture a profiler without running an apk?

Comment: Yes, it also works for binaries - still need debug build though. You get to choose your executable/apk that you wish to capture a profile of.

Comment: Just as a comment, the link to this answer might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78009101/how-to-profile-opencl-code-on-android-run-on-an-arm-mali-gpu/78087431#78087431